# [r][shiny] how to render ui from a string?

Tags: r, shiny

I have ui component stored in the data frame or vector as character.

```
chr <- "fluidRow( numericInput(inputId='a'), numericInput(inputId='b') ) "
```

I want to render the character as shiny ui. I tried:

server.r

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$ui <- renderUI({   
      eval(parse(text=chr))
    })

})
```

ui.r

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    uiOutput("ui")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, very cool idea. Your code's problem is actually not in your eval parse method, but in your numeric input arguments. They are missing a `value` and `label` input.

Try:

server.R

```
chr <- "numericInput(inputId='a', value = 1, label = 1)" 

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$ui <- renderUI({   
    eval(parse(text=chr))
  })

})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ui")
)
)
```